# Getting the Protocol of an URL using indexOf method

Tags: java, indexof

I am trying to only return the protocol of the URL...the directions says this...

> The sample url shows https as the protocol but there are other different protocols as well. So you cannot hard code in the endIndex of the substring method. You will need to use the indexOf method to get the end index.

```
public String getProtocol(String url) {
    
    url = "https://www.samplewebsite.com/sample-page/1";
    int startProtocol = url.indexOf("https");
    int endProtocol = url.indexOf("://");
    
    
    String protocol = url.substring(startProtocol, endProtocol );
    
    return protocol;
}
```

Getting an error saying:

```
Make sure you did not hard code the end Index ===\> expected \<http\> was expected but was \<https\>
```

Comment: Do not override `url` parameter. This is provided by the test. Also, `startProtocol` should always be `0`, so you don't really need it. Nor, should you hard-code `"https://"` as you can have other protocols, as the instructions say (i.e. your code fails on `http://`, `tcp://`, etc)

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? I assume you want to find out the protocol used for any given URL? If so, take a look at the URL class in the JavaDoc and its constructor using a String parameter and the getProtocol() method.

Comment: The URL may not necessarily have `//` after the `:`. The protocol is simply terminated by the first `:` so that's all you need to use.

Comment: Once I took out the
" url = "https://www.samplewebsite.com/sample-page/1"; "

the code worked..thank you all :)